# What format comes out when you export from OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson

I am trying to export this [osm](http://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=11/29.9900/-89.9708&layers=T) output (and then convert it into geojson).  I click export and get a file called "map." What format is this file in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is in .osm format and is based on xml. you can read about it [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML).